# Operator precedence in Python -PEMDAS

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I read about python following PEMDAS that is precedence of multiply is more than division.

I ran the following script

```
print 6*2/1*2
```

Thus python should interpret this like 12/2 i.e 6 , since precedence of multiplication is more than division.

But, the answer is 24.
Could anyone let me know where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: "[...] since precedence of multiplication is more than division." Uh? Since when?

Comment: The problem is wherever you read that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` has the same [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) as `/`. Operators in the same group evaluate left to right, so your expression evaluates as:

```
6*2 = 12
/ 1 = 12
* 2 = 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Order of precedence in Python

P

E

M
D `Left to right`

A
S `Left to right`